# Google App Engine - SSL InsecurePlatformWarning

Tags: python, google-app-engine, ssl, python-requests, urllib3

I'm using python's [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library inside Google App Engine to send GET requests to a private server.  When I make the request I get this warning:

```
requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:79: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning
```

According to the [documentation](https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning) that points to, I need to either upgrade past Python 2.7.x which GAE uses, or use pyopenssl.  Since I don't believe that I can force GAE to use Python 2.7.9 I tried to use pyopenssl.

Following the instruction on the page, I've downloaded the three libraries suggested into the lib directory of my app and where I use requests I try to inject pyopenssl into urllib3 with:

```
import requests.packages.urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl
requests.packages.urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl.inject_into_urllib3()
```

This however, fails in the devserver and the production server with the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~servicey1564/1.383321878696068897/main.py", line 24, in <module>
    from API import setupautomatorAPI
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~servicey1564/1.383321878696068897/API.py", line 12, in <module>
    from ServiceActivationTest import uploadSAT, getSATsForService
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~servicey1564/1.383321878696068897/ServiceActivationTest/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from requests.packages.urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl as pyopenssl
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~servicey1564/1.383321878696068897/lib/requests/packages/__init__.py", line 95, in load_module
    raise ImportError("No module named '%s'" % (name,))
ImportError: No module named 'requests.packages.urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl'
```

This import statement works fine in the Python interpreter, and works if I take off the pyopenssl on the end.  pyopenssl is also the first .py file besides __init__.py files in that path.

Am I doing something wrong here?  Is there an easier way to fix the InsecurePlatformWarning?

UPDATE: After going to the sockets API page(Thanks shazow!) I found that part of my problem was that httplib was misbehaving because I lacked an environment variable.  This didn't get rid of the warning, but my certificate is being accepted now!

Comment: Hm, I don't have a full answer yet, but some hints: I don't believe PyOpenSSL works on AppEngine, since it's a compiled module. AppEngine provides its own version of things like that. Maybe you need to enable the `sockets` API to get a proper SSLContext? https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/sockets/

Comment: I believe that I have sockets enabled.  My understanding is that sockets are automatically available if billing is enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I'm not 100% sure this is what you mean, but this might be a more relevant answer to your question:)

Turns out there is a new behaviour that is a bug in urllib3 manifested by AppEngine changing their default modules available.

Traditionally, urllib3 tries to `import ssl` which would fail on old AppEngine, then it would fallback to plain `httplib` which is AppEngine's `URLFetch` behind the scenes. Now, looks like AppEngine added an `ssl` module as part of their sockets beta, which screwed up our fallback.

This bug is being investigated here: https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/issues/583

For the time being, you can manually override the default HTTPSConnection type that urllib3 uses to be the plain `httplib` one rather than the `PyOpenSSL` one by doing something like this before making any pools:

```
from urllib3.connection import UnverifiedHTTPSConnection
from urllib3.connectionpool import HTTPSConnectionPool

# Override the default Connection class for the HTTPSConnectionPool.
HTTPSConnectionPool.ConnectionCls = UnverifiedHTTPSConnection
```

Now whenever urllib3 uses an `HTTPSConnectionPool` (which things like `PoolManager` allocate automatically), it will use `UnverifiedHTTPSConnection`s which are equivalent to the [URL Fetch service on AppEngine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/).

Once issue [#583](https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/issues/583) is fixed, you won't need to do this anymore.

Comment: Trying this import: `from urllib3.connection import UnverifiedHTTPSConnection` raises `No module named urllib3.connection` for me. Any suggestions?

Comment: @kolinko Update to the latest urllib3, currently v1.10.4. :) `pip install -U urllib3`

Comment: @shazow, is this UnverifiedHTTPSConnection any more secure? (I'm assuming, based on the name, that it doesn't verify the HTTPS certificate). Is this approach any better than just disabling urllib3 warnings? Does Google App Engine not support a mechanism for doing verified requests?

Comment: @ClintDoriot You're correct to assume that it is not more secure. https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/issues/583 is still outstanding. If this bug is affecting you, the Google AppEngine developer advocate team asked me to instruct people to contact them directly.

Comment: Is that a different group than Google Cloud Support? We pay for a support package, but they generally wont help with specific coding issues.

Comment: @ClintDoriot I'm sorry I don't work with the team, all I know is that you're supposed to reach out to your support contact if you have one or open stackoverflow questions with the google-app-engine tag. :(

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following to app.yaml, as per the [sockets API page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/sockets/), allows requests based http requests to deliver their certificates properly.

```
env_variables:
   GAE_USE_SOCKETS_HTTPLIB : 'anyvalue'
```

This does not eliminate the InsecurePlatformWarning, my particular requests don't seem to be affected by whatever is causing this warning.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve the InsecurePlatformWarning issue on Google AppEngine is to simply set `version: latest` for library ssl in app.yaml.

```
libraries:
- name: ssl
  version: latest
```

While some people may still have `version: 2.7`, like I did.

Once this is set, there is no need to modify GAE_USE_SOCKETS_HTTPLIB as suggested by Steven Wendling.   No need to install additional libraries either.